# Confused about "\n" spacing with cout to console - c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to leave a space each time I print to the console, but I'm confused why I need to use `cout << "\n";` so many times. I'm like 10 hours new to programing if you can't tell.

```
cout << "\n";
cout << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = " << number1 + number2 << "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << number1 << " - " << number2 << " = " << number1 - number2;
cout << "\n";
```

```
cout << "\n";
cout << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = " << number1 + number2;
cout << "\n";
cout << number1 << " - " << number2 << " = " << number1 - number2;
cout << "\n";
```

The top one works, but the bottom doesn't. Can somebody explain why?

I was able to make it a lot cleaner and understand it now, thanks.

```
cout << "\n" << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = " << number1 + number2 << "\n";
cout << "\n" << number1 << " - " << number2 << " = " << number1 - number2 << "\n";
```

Comment: "\n" is the newline character. Consider if you were typing into a text editor, how many times would you have to press the enter key to get the same output?

Comment: `\n` is a line break. If you want to leave a *blank* line, you need two line breaks, so you need to write the `\n` character twice.

Comment: `\n` is a newline.  On a console, the cursor will move to the left margin and down one line for each newline.  Your "working" examples produce two newlines between the lines of non-blank output.  Your not working example produces only one newline between the lines of non-blank output.  So the output of the two will be visually different (more clear lines between lines of text in your "working" examples).

Answer (score 1):

A little theory: the newline character ( \n ) is called an escape sequence, and it forces the cursor to change its position to the beginning of the next line on the screen. This results in a new line.

If you need a space between adjacent lines, you can write like this:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    int number1 = 3;
    int number2 = 5;
    cout << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = " << number1 + number2 << "\n\n";
    cout << number1 << " - " << number2 << " = " << number1 - number2 << endl;
    cout <<endl;
    cout<< "SOME STR";

    return 0;
}
```

Is \n better than Endl?
While the difference is not obvious in smaller programs, endl performs significantly worse than \n because of the constant flushing of the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` character breaks a line and moves output to the next line. If you want a blank line, you need two `\n` characters in a row.

Comment: My lord I feel dumb now haha, Thank you that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @otis We all started knowing nothing, you pick up information one piece at a time. You may find the [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) contains a lot of relevant information. Take a look at ASCII `10` (`0xa`) which is the `'\n'` character....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- although the **value** is the same, `'\n'` in C or C++ code is not as ASCII code; it is an escape sequence that tells the runtime library to write **whatever is needed** to start a new line. On UNIX systems that's `0x0A` (ASCII LF); on Windows systems it's `0x0D 0x0A` (ASCII CR LF); on old Macs it's `0x0D` (ASCII CR).

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes, but the distinction for someone learning what `"/n"` (as originally in the title) is, beginning with the ASCII chart that explains the characters used as escape sequences is a good place to start. Explaining how the newline interacts with the runtime library can wait until I/O 101 is done. Yes, correct you are on mac pre-OSX, that used the `CR` for the newline -- rather an odd duck. Or backing up further, Vax systems used the `FF` character. I don't recall what the old Sperry machines used -- thankfully they were going out as I was coming in...

Answer (score 0):

It is called an escape sequence, this one is for a new line. But there are more : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: Didnt know about that website but thank you! Ill mess around with those now

Comment: That website is one of the best for resources for C++